# Introduce new Python version to conda-forge feedstock

Tags: python, conda

A conda package I rely on is available in the [conda-forge channel](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge) (=there exists a feedstock already) but not yet for the Python version `x.y` . Which steps need to be taken to bring it to that version on conda-forge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by Anthony Scopatz one needs to locally update the feedstock with `conda-smithy` and bring these changes to the appropriate branch on GitHub.

The steps in detail are:

1. Clone the repo.
2. Install (or update) `conda-smithy` in your root environment:

   ```
   conda (source) deactivate
   conda install conda-smithy
   conda install conda=4.2 # see below
   ```
3. Rerender the feedstock from your root environment:

   ```
   cd <feedstock-repo>/
   conda smithy rerender
   ```

   You might see warnings about missing tokens to CI services and anaconda, but you can safely ignore these.
4. Commit all changes, push them to your Github fork, and open a pull request.
5. After the pull request gets merged, the package gets build by the CI servers which might take several hours depending on their queues. Eventually the package should be available for the Python version `x.y`.

---

**The currently most recent version of conda, 4.3.14 [is not supported](https://github.com/conda-forge/conda-smithy/issues/451) by `conda-smithy`. Hence as a workaround, a downgrade to conda 4.2 is currently necessary.**

Answer (score 3):

You should run `conda smithy rerender` in the feedstock repo locally on a new branch, push it up to your fork, and open a pull request.

Comment: This complains first that I don't have tokens for circle, appveyor, and anaconda and then fails with a `KeyError: 'python-3.3.0-pro0.tar.bz2'` in line 212 `version_matrix.py` of `conda_build_all`. Do you think this is related? Do I need tokens for all these services?

Comment: You should not need to have those tokens IIRC.  I think the tokens are just warnings.  Note that this will stage the diff, so you need to run `git diff --staged` to see if it is working correctly.

Comment: The issue I ran into is [a known issue with conda 4.3](https://github.com/conda-forge/conda-smithy/issues/451). The mentioned workaround downgrading to 4.2 worked for me.